# Can a PST file contain a PST file?

Tags: recursion, outlook-redemption, pst

I'm working with PST files using outlook-redemption and I've got a conceptual question: Can a PST file contain a PST file? i.e. are PST files recursive-enabled?

I know that a PST file can contain an email item with a PST attachment, but is it possible for a PST to simply have a child PST file?

Fingers crossed the answer is no (huge amount of avoided complexity...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. An attachment that is a PST file is possible, but that is it.

Answer (score 1):

PST file is a personal storage table and it contains mailbox data such as emails, contacts, journals, tasks, and others. But it cannot contain child PST file.